# Cannot render distill article in a targets pipeline

Tags: r, targets-r-package, r-distill

I'm new to targets ecosystem. I could not create a distill article from my targets pipeline although it works when I set the output to `html_document` in yaml. I have tried googling but couldn't find anything useful. Any help would be appreciated.

My RStudio is version 1.4.1717. I got this error message upon running `tar_make()`:

```
Error: callr subprocess failed: Distill articles cannot be previewed in this version of RStudio.
Please update to version 1.2.718 or higher at https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/

Visit https://books.ropensci.org/targets/debugging.html for debugging advice.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Here is a minimal code example.

Code in `_targets.R`

```
library(targets)
library(tarchetypes)

tar_plan(
  tar_target(dat, iris),
  tar_render(test_report, "test.Rmd")
)
```

Here are the contents of my Rmd file. Most of them are from the template.

````
---
title: "Test"
description: |
  A new article created using the Distill format.
author:
  - name: Nora Jones 
    url: https://example.com/norajones
    affiliation: Spacely Sprockets
    affiliation_url: https://example.com/spacelysprokets
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: distill::distill_article
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r load-targets, include=FALSE}
tar_load(dat)
```

```{r}
summary(dat)
```
````

**Session info**

```
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] igraph_1.2.6      rstudioapi_0.13   knitr_1.33        magrittr_2.0.1    tidyselect_1.1.1 
 [6] R6_2.5.1          rlang_0.4.11      fansi_0.5.0       tools_4.1.0       targets_0.7.0    
[11] data.table_1.14.0 xfun_0.25         utf8_1.2.2        cli_3.0.1         withr_2.4.2      
[16] ellipsis_0.3.2    yaml_2.2.1        digest_0.6.27     tibble_3.1.3      lifecycle_1.0.0  
[21] crayon_1.4.1      processx_3.5.2    purrr_0.3.4       callr_3.7.0       vctrs_0.3.8      
[26] ps_1.6.0          codetools_0.2-18  glue_1.4.2        compiler_4.1.0    pillar_1.6.2     
[31] pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Comment: It's hard to say why you are getting that error, I cannot reproduce it locally. But maybe your system is finding an old version of the RStudio IDE. If you have old versions of the IDE, I suggest removing them and trying again. Also, do you get the same error if you avoid `targets` and just just call `rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd")` in the console manually? (Note: this is different from the Knit button, which has its own way of working.)

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. I don't have any older version of RStudio IDE installed in my system. `rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd")` ran successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same issue.

From [here](https://github.com/rstudio/distill/blob/master/R/rstudio.R) you can see that `distill` checks for the version first by trying the `rstudioapi` (which fails) and then by looking for an environment variable called "RSTUDIO_VERSION", which does not exist on my system. When this fails, it uses a default value of 1.1, which fails the check of having at least version 1.2.7...

There is a simple, if slightly hacky, solution which is to just manually set the environment variable that `distill` is looking for at the top of your script. I.e., your Rmd file would become:

````
---
title: "Test"
description: |
  A new article created using the Distill format.
author:
  - name: Nora Jones 
    url: https://example.com/norajones
    affiliation: Spacely Sprockets
    affiliation_url: https://example.com/spacelysprokets
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: distill::distill_article
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
# Add environment variable
Sys.setenv("RSTUDIO_VERSION" = '1.4.1725')
```

```{r load-targets, include=FALSE}
tar_load(dat)
```

```{r}
summary(dat)
```
````

This works totally fine for me. If you're worried about this having ongoing effects, you can remove it afterwards (`Sys.unsetenv("RSTUDIO_VERSION")`)